# Go implicit conversion to interface does memory allocation?

Tags: go

When defining a function with variadic arguments of type `interface{}` (e.g. `Printf`), the arguments are apparently implicitly converted to interface instances.

Does this conversion imply memory allocation? Is this conversion fast? When concerned by code efficiency, should I avoid using variadic functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best explanation i found about the interface memory allocation in Go is still this article from Rus Cox, one of the core Go programmer. It's well worth to read it.

**http://research.swtch.com/interfaces**

I picked up some of the most interesting parts:

> Values stored in interfaces might be arbitrarily large, but only one
>   word is dedicated to holding the value in the interface structure, so
>   the assignment allocates a chunk of memory on the heap and records the
>   pointer in the one-word slot.
>
> ...
>
> Calling fmt.Printf(), the Go compiler generates code that calls the
>   appropriate function pointer from the itable, passing the interface
>   value's data word as the function's first (in this example, only)
>   argument.
>
> Go's dynamic type conversions mean that it isn't reasonable for the
>   compiler or linker to precompute all possible itables: there are too
>   many (interface type, concrete type) pairs, and most won't be needed.
>   Instead, the compiler generates a type description structure for each
>   concrete type like Binary or int or func(map[int]string). Among other
>   metadata, the type description structure contains a list of the
>   methods implemented by that type.
>
> ...
>
> The interface runtime computes the itable by looking for each method
>   listed in the interface type's method table in the concrete type's
>   method table. The runtime caches the itable after generating it, so
>   that this correspondence need only be computed once.
>
> ...
>
> If the interface type involved is empty—it has no methods—then the
>   itable serves no purpose except to hold the pointer to the original
>   type. In this case, the itable can be dropped and the value can point
>   at the type directly.

Because Go has the hint of static typing to go along with the dynamic method lookups, it can move the lookups back from the call sites to the point when the value is stored in the interface.

Comment: I gave you the answer because the cited text explains why converting a value to an interface might be "expensive" and should be avoided. This conversion is not free.

Answer (score 1):

Converting to an `interface{}` is a separate concept from variadic arguments which are contained in a slice and can be of any type. However these are all probably free in the sense of allocations as long as they don't escape to the heap (in the GC toolchain).

The excess allocations you would see from `fmt` functions like `Printf` are going to be from reflection rather than from the use of `interface{}` or variadic arguments.

If you're concerned with efficiency though, avoiding indirection will always be more efficient than not, so using the correct value types will yield more efficient code. The difference can be minimal though, so benchmark the code first before concerning yourself with minor optimizations.

Comment: Your answer is not clear enough. If I pass an interface as argument to a variadic function, a simple reference copy is performed. That is cheap. But if I pass another value like an integer or a slice for instance, a conversion to an interface data structure must take place. Would this interface data structure be allocated on the heap or on the stack ? Heap allocation has usually a significant performance penalty. I however followed your advise in the last paragraph and got rid of the variadic API.

Comment: @chmike: there no such thing as a "reference copy" in Go. Everything in Go is a value, and everything is passed by value. A variadic argument has _nothing_ do to with interfaces, it's simply syntactic sugar around a slice and adding it to this conversation only confuses the issue. If you pass an interface to an interface argument, the interface value is copied which is 2 words. These are stack allocated when possible if they don't escape (go has essentially unlimited stack).

Comment: There is a misunderstanding. I referred to the two pointers in the interface value as the references. The two pointers are indeed copied on the stack. If the argument is not an interface it has to be converted to an interface. My question was of course considering the case when the argument to a variadic function of `[]interface{}` type is not an interface and needs to be converted to an interface. My main concern was about base types like `int` or `string`.

Comment: @chmike: I was trying to address the 2 interface questions, "Does this conversion imply memory allocation" - no it does not, because it's stack allocated if the value doesn't escape;  "Is this conversion fast?" -- it's just a copy and and 2 pointers. What you do with the interface in the function makes orders of magnitude more difference than the time it takes to copy the value into the interface argument (on my system an `interface{}` argument takes about 3ns more to call than a singe word value, provided the arguments all fit in a single cache line).

Answer (score 0):

Go passes arguments copy_by_value, so it does memory allocation anyway. You always should better avoid using interface{} if possible. In described case your function will need to reflect arguments to use them. Reflection is quite expensive operation that's why `fmt.Printf()` is so slow.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Printf doesn't use reflection, and use type assertion instead [https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions] which would be efficient when using interfaces. My current assumption is that the critical point is converting none interface values to interface values. The answer of @Simo Endre provides an explanation why it is slow. It is not only due to the potentially required heap allocations.  It's because of the methods lookup.

Comment: Passing arguments by copy doesn't mean that it does allocation. Those are mostly passed through the preallocated stack memory, unless shared through a pointer.